# .getJSON won't execute for input

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, navigator

I have 2 sections

- The **first section**, I want to get location input from the user. This is where .getJSON doesn't execute.
- The **second section**, I check if geolocation is compatible with the browser, and if permission is given, .getJSON executes. This one works just fine.

I don't think `if(navigator.geolocation)` checks for if permission was granted, only that geolocation is compatible with the browser.

This  line in section 1 `$.getJSON(address, function(data)` doesn't execute like it does in section 2. If i place `console.log(address) right before it, it shows, but inside the .getJSON scope it doesn't.

Confused as to what is happening since the functions are identical.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //GET STUFF FUNCTION
  function getStuff(address) {
    api = address; //**EDIT** changed to address
    console.log("clicking or entering works yes");
    $.getJSON(api, function(data) {
      console.log("yay it works");
    });
  };
  // SECTION 1
  $("#searchForm").submit(function(e) {
    var searchInput = $("#searchInput").val();
    var address = "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + searchInput + "&appid=?";

    e.preventDefault();
    getStuff(address);

  });

  $("#searchInput").keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
      $("#searchBtn").click();
    };
  });

  //SECTION 2
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      lat = position.coords.latitude;
      lon = position.coords.longitude;

      var address = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=' + lat + '&lon=' + lon + '&appid=?';

      //tried to use this function for search
      getStuff(address);
    });
```

I tried minifying this the best I could, I'm unsure of how to do  AJAX requests on a fiddle.
edit:update https://jsfiddle.net/mq10ps5c/10/

Thank you all, and any critiques are much appreciated

Comment: Why does one URL have http:// and the other one does not?

Comment: Thank you Thank you! That was the problem, I'm totally embarrassed, but thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside Section 1 and 2 you set the address and then call `GetStuff` inside this `GetStuff` function you're not referring to address, instead you reference `api`

Change your `GetStuff` function to the below:

```
function getStuff(address) {
 api = address == null ? "/echo/JSON/" : address;
 console.log("clicking or entering works yes");
 $.getJSON(api, function(data) {
  console.log("yay it works");
 });
};
```

first check to see if address is null if so set `api` to "/echo/JSON/" otherwise set `api` to `address` value.

Comment: My mistake, I was trying to get the AJAX request to work with fiddle before, it was set to address, the input section still doesnt work but the navigator section does

Comment: Fixed the problem, I had a really simple syntax error with the url, i didn't add `http://` before the address. Thanks for showing me how the /echo/JSON/ works.